# Change column type of imported data set in shiny

Tags: r, csv, import, shiny, reactive

I would like to change a selected column type of an imported to date. The operations should be done in a shiny app. The data is in csv [file](https://ufile.io/mcb8q). In this data set, the column which should be changed is called "date", however, ideally it should be possible to input the name of the column which type should be changed.

The code I've written:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(5,
             fileInput('file1', "Input a csv file:"),
             accept=c('text/csv', 
                      'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                      '.csv'),
             checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE)),
      column(3,
             radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                          c(Comma=',',
                            Semicolon=';',
                            Tab='\t'),
                          ',')
      ),
      column(3,
             radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                          c(None='',
                            'Double Quote'='"',
                            'Single Quote'="'"),
                          '"')
      )
    ),
    tableOutput("first.two"),
    fluidRow(
      column(4,
             textInput("time.var", h3("Input time variable:"),
                       value = ""))
    ),
    p(strong("Variables to choose from:"), textOutput("possible.variables")),
    p(strong("Classes of variables"), textOutput("variable.classes"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  dset.in <- reactive({
    infile <- input$file1
    if(is.null(infile)){
      return(NULL)
    }

    df <- read.csv(infile$datapath, header = input$header,
                   sep = input$sep,quote = input$quote)

    return(df)}
  )

  # Change column type to date
  # When three lines below are commented out, the code works
  dset.in()$date.input <- observeEvent({
    dset.in()[,input$time.var] <- lubridate::date_decimal(dset.in()[,input$time.var])
  })

  output$first.two <- renderTable({head(dset.in(), 2)})

  output$possible.variables <- renderText(
    names(dset.in())
  )
  output$variable.classes <- renderText(
    sapply(dset.in(), class)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It produces the following error:

> Warning in if (!is.na(attribValue)) { : 
>    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 
>    
>   Warning in charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) : 
>     argument should be a character vector of length 1 
>   all but the first element will be ignored 
>    
>   Warning in body(fun) : argument is not a function 
>    
>   Warning: Error in eval: argument "expr" is missing, with no default 
>   Stack trace (innermost first): 
>       44: eval 
>       43: makeFunction 
>       42: exprToFunction 
>       41: observeEvent 
>       40: server [#16] 
>        4:  
>        3: do.call 
>        2: print.shiny.appobj 
>        1:  
>    
>   Error in eval(call("function", args, body), env) :  
>     argument "expr" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
  modified_dset <- eventReactive(input$time.var, {
    dset.in()[, input$time.var] <- lubridate::date_decimal(dset.in()[,input$time.var])
  })
```

And use this `modified_dset` everywhere else.